# Connect to SQLite Database using Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to connect to SQLite database with Ecplise but I have some errors. This is my Java code and the errors that I get on output. Please see if you can help me. Thank you in advance.

```
package jdb;
import java.sql.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Applications/MAMP/db/sqlite/test.sqlite");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists people;");
    stat.executeUpdate("create table people (name, occupation);");
    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into people values (?, ?);");
```

```
prep.setString(1, "Gandhi");
prep.setString(2, "politics");
prep.addBatch();
prep.setString(1, "Turing");
prep.setString(2, "computers");
prep.addBatch();
prep.setString(1, "Wittgenstein");
prep.setString(2, "smartypants");
prep.addBatch();

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
prep.executeBatch();
conn.setAutoCommit(true);

ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from people;");
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
  System.out.println("job = " + rs.getString("occupation"));
}
rs.close();
conn.close();
```

}
}

ans that what I get in Ecplise :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at jdb.Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have sqlitejdbc-v056.jar in your Eclipse classpath

Answer (score 1):

While can retrieve the database in this way also but their is simple way to set the database like download the SQLlite database browser then u can easily upgrade the data. if u gonna go in this way then i will get back to u soon.